# Why do assemblers like GAS output more than just a binary?

Tags: assembly, executable, gnu-assembler

According to Encyclopedia Britanica assembly language is

> mostly of symbolic equivalents of a particular computer’s machine language.

If this is true why do assemblers like GAS output files with headers?

I am certain that the ELF/ Mach-O/ PE headers are not "machine language".

So why don't *assemblers* **just** *assemble* the assembly language and leave formatting the binary up to the linker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that the machine runs straight assembly but the operating system has to set up a place for the binary to execute. This is why you have things like ELF headers. Your OS needs to know where the code is, BSS section, where to load data, etc.... Without this information the OS cannot correctly load that if you just give it raw assembly.

If you have assembly code with inline data (coded into the instructions) then you could say that headers are unnecessary but that's rarely the case.

Comment: why can't the headers be added in the linking stage? Whatever does this though, is not an assembler.

Comment: @Hawken The linker needs the header information as well if not it doesn't know what sections are where.

Comment: But doesn't that fall out of the responsibility of the assembler? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep the section data in a separate file?

Comment: @Hawken That would just make things a lot bulkier than they need to be. It's easy enough to encode that data in the file and makes loading a lot simpler. Imagine having to find the corresponding file to find the metadata header for it. This sounds more error prone to me and more of an annoyance to implement for no benefit.

Comment: but as it is, running on a mac myself, I need to get a different copy of GAS for ELF, and another for PE if I want to make windows binaries. It just seems bizarre to require a 'linker' to make a flat binary; rather than having a linker 'link' a flat binary into a OS-specific executable format. Feels backwards. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Comment: nasm outputs both formats if im not mistaken, anyway it does seem bizzarre from your perspective but try implementing it some other way :)